# Pushing object into subdoc's subdoc in Mongoose? How can it be done?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose

I just can't seem to find any answer to this question anywhere.

My schema model looks somewhat like that in the DB:

```
    User{
    "email"
    "password"
    "eventList" : [ 
        {
            "eventName"
            "allParticipants" : [
                              "email"
                              "password"
        ]}
```

Apparently, javascript doesn't like if I want to push the email and password like that:

```
const email = req.body.email;
const password = req.body.password;

    const participant = new User({
          email: email,
          password: password,

        });

    User.eventList.participants.push({ 
        allParticipants: participant,
        });
```

How would you tackle pushing object into a nested array's nested array?
Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

**1. You're trying to set your data on `User`, which is your Mongoose model, rather than `participant`, which is an instance of your User**

You need to use `participant.eventList` rather than `User.eventList`. The latter refers to your Mongoose model, and wouldn't exist.

**2. eventList probably doesn't exist when you create your user.**

Unless you've set a default value, when you create your User, `participant.eventList` is empty. You need to push an object to that array, which should have the keys `eventName` and `allParticipants` according to your schema.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The reason why the participiants are on the eventlist, is because one user might belong to several events and I want them to be able to choose from a list first. Then, to a certain event,  people should be pushed in just like on Facebook.

Comment: I've been wondering... Do you think it would work, if I created 2 schemas for 1 database? 1 for the users and one for the events. And then the event's could be pushed into users and I would call them only participants on the client side?